# what is the API for VSTS

Tags: migration, alm, azure-devops-rest-api

I am having a scenario where in I need to migrate the artifacts from HP ALM to VSTS for test management. I know about the ALM API and have worked with that before for exporting defects, and test cases but I am not aware of any such things for VSTS ( am very new with it) and want to create a task and then create a bug with the help of the adapter code and move the details from alm to vsts.
Can anyone please help me get the VSTS API, or some sample adapters based on which I can start coding for the VSTS API?

N.B: I tried finding it over google but no luck till now.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can try to use VSTS/TFS SDK https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.ExtendedClient/ (Check my update)

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use [OpsHub tool](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vs-publisher-1455028.OpsHubVisualStudioOnlineMigrationUtility).

Another tool: [Microsoft Visual Studio Online Integration](http://www.kovair.com/adapters/visual-studio-online-integration/)

Regarding API, you can try to use VSTS/TFS sdk: [Microsoft Team Foundation Server Extended Client](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.ExtendedClient/). You can check the source code of [vstssync migrator](https://github.com/nkdAgility/vsts-sync-migration) (Ove mentioned)

Answer (score 0):

Another option is vstssync migrator created by mrhinsh
https://github.com/nkdAgility/vsts-sync-migration
There is the code to get you started with your adapter.